# Modern alternatives to DRESOL Riccati solver

Tags: software, reference-request, ode

I am looking for a modern version or an alternative to the [DRESOL](http://www.netlib.org/ode/dresol.f) package for differential matrix Riccati equations. The main issue that the original package uses single-precision type `float` which seems to be not accurate enough for my purposes. Available Matlab alternatives are also appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [SLICOT](http://www.slicot.org/index.php)? I'm not sure they would count as modern for many definitions of that term, but they do support double precision, as [this help page](http://www.slicot.org/shared/doc/SB02PD.html) shows.

I do note that, while the web site claims that the code is available under the GPL, none of the links to the sources seem to work.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to solve _differential_ Riccati equation dX/dt = A21(t) + A22(t)*X -X*A11(t) - X*A12(t)*X.

Comment: Argh - I read differential and thought continuous - sorry.

Comment: Do the coefficient matrices depends explicitly on time or are they constant in time? 
If so you can use the modified Davison-Maki method to solve the problem. See here https://zenodo.org/record/4460618#.Y24dQYKZOdf for implementation and http://dx.doi.org/10.25673/68198 section 6.4 for the theory.